# How do I specify a particular column order in pivot_wider

Tags: r, dplyr

Dataframe `indrur` consists of variable `S447.1` that indicates mode of transport. I use `dplyr` to group by the variable and convert it to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)      
    indrurmodes<-indrur %>% 
          group_by(V024,V025,V190) %>%count(S447.1) %>% 
          pivot_wider(names_from = S447.1,values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

It gives me the following output. But I want the columns in a particular order - `GovtAmb,OthAmb,Jeep,Tempo,Scooter,Bus,Cart,Foot,NA`. I have to execute the above code for multiple filtered dataframes. Each time, I get a different order. This makes it difficult to perform further arithmetic operations where I use column index as reference.How do I maintain the desired column order?

```
       V024     V025    V190 GovtAmb Jeep   Tempo Foot  NA     OthAmb Scooter  Bus  Cart
3   Andaman     Rural   Middle  67   21     16     16   615     2     3        4      0
4   Andaman     Rural   Richer  66   39     20     3    617     2     1        0      0
5   Andaman     Rural   Richest 21   18     5      2    278     0     2        5      1
6   Andhra      Rural   Poorest 25   0      35     4    294     5     0        6      0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have two options.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Order of the columns you want
vec <- c("GovtAmb","OthAmb","Jeep","Tempo","Scooter","Bus","Cart","Foot",NA)
```

1) Using `pivot_wider` :

`pivot_wider` returns the column in the order they appear. So you can `arrange` the data in the order you want before using `pivot_wider`.

```
indrur %>% 
   group_by(V024,V025,V190) %>%
   count(S447.1) %>% 
   arrange(match(S447.1, vec)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = S447.1,values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

2) Use the older `spread` which gives the column order based on factor levels.

```
indrur %>% 
  group_by(V024,V025,V190) %>%
  count(S447.1) %>% 
  mutate(S447.1 = factor(S447.1, levels = vec)) %>%
  spread(S447.1,n,fill = 0)
```

Comment: `spread`'s behavior is simply better in my opinion. I wish pivot_wider worked like that...

Answer (score 3):

Since [tidyr 1.1.0](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#tidyr-110) this is now possible with the argument `names_sort = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

## Factor level order (change if necessary)
levels(fish_encounters$station)

## With `names_sort = FALSE`, column names are ordered by first appearance.
fish_encounters %>%
  arrange(desc(row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = station, values_from = seen, names_sort = FALSE)

## With `names_sort = TRUE`, columns names are sorted (e.g. based on factor level order)
fish_encounters %>%
  arrange(desc(row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = station, values_from = seen, names_sort = TRUE)
```